# Views: Insert Profile2 information in a node

Tags: views, display-suite

I have a  problem and here's my graphical illustration of it:
[image]

I have tried many things that didn't work. I think the answer has something to do with adding a relationship with a node field, but I don't know how to get it to work here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to have an [entity reference](https://drupal.org/project/entityreference) field on the node type that allows you to reference a user as the creator of the necklace.
2. Then you want a node view that has a contextual filter of nid, that uses node id from the url as a default value when no contextual filter value is provided.
3. Then you can add a relationship to the user via the entity reference field you added.
4. Then add a relationship for the profile2 profile, so you can use the profile fields in your view.
5. Add a block view display.
6. Add the block to your node pages.

Comment: Thank you! I've found a detailed guide here too, which explains I also need to add a  contextual filter for Content:NID https://drupal.org/node/1841004

Comment: Yep, that's step 2 of my post.

Comment: Haha yes I just realised that I missed it. I guess the illustration in the link was easier to for me understand because I never used contextual filters before.